# Json Result DataTable JQuery from MVC to .NET CORE 2.2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm converting a function that populates a JQuery DataTables from MVC to .NET CORE 2.2.
In MVC it ​​works and the grid is populated, in .NET CORE I saw that the mvc JSONRESULT namespace is different, can this be the problem? the compilation is ok and the data is there but the datatable tells me as if it doesn't find the ID field.

To make it compile on .NET CORE I had to insert a NULL as a parameter when I instantiate JsonResult and remove JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet at the end.

```cs
// MVC
public ActionResult GetData(searchNews searchAdv)
{
    // Initialization.   
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    try
    {
        // Initialization.
        string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
        string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
        string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
        string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
        int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
        int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);

        // Loading.   
        List<Models.News> data = c.dsListaNews();

        // Loading drop down lists.   
        result = this.Json(new
        {
            draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
            recordsTotal = totalRecords,
            recordsFiltered = recFilter,
            data = data
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

```cs
//ASP.NET CORE 2.2
public ActionResult GetData(searchNews searchAdv)
{
    // Initialization.   
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(null);

    string search = Request.Form["search[value]"][0];
    string draw = Request.Form["draw"][0];
    string order = Request.Form["order[0][column]"][0];
    string orderDir = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"][0];
    int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["start"][0]);
    int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["length"][0]);            

    // Loading.
    List<Models.News> data = c.dsListaNews(conn);

    // Loading drop down lists.   
    result = this.Json(new
    {
        draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
        recordsTotal = totalRecords,
        recordsFiltered = recFilter,
        data = data
    });

    // Return info.   
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Share us the json response from mvc and mvc core. Is there any mini demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: In The JSON MVC Core the field-name of json data is lowercase. Now is ok!!! Thank Yoy @Tao Zhou

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
return Json(new
            {
                draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
                recordsTotal = totalRecords,
                recordsFiltered = recFilter,
                data = data
            });
```

without declaring the JsonResult variable and use in .Net-Core IActionResult instead of ActionResult.

Comment: nothing, same mistake.
DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter 'ID' for row 0, column 0